# how to display the name of wifi AP using reachability wifi example on iphone

Tags: iphone

i want to display the infomation of my WIFI AP to which i am connected , how to do that ???

```
+ (Reachability*) reachabilityForLocalWiFi;
{//NSLog(@"cheking all addresss ");
    struct sockaddr_in localWifiAddress;

    bzero(&localWifiAddress, sizeof(localWifiAddress));
    localWifiAddress.sin_len = sizeof(localWifiAddress);
    localWifiAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    //NSLog(@"Destination%@",localWifiAddress.sin_len);

    // IN_LINKLOCALNETNUM is defined in <netinet/in.h> as 169.254.0.0
    localWifiAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(IN_LINKLOCALNETNUM);
    Reachability* retVal = [self reachabilityWithAddress: &localWifiAddress];

    if(retVal!= NULL)
    {
        retVal->localWiFiRef = YES;

        //printf("%i",localWifiAddress);
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to find the name of AP to which you are connected??